# Android IllegalStateException: No instantiated fragment for index #0

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main drawer activity with LinearLayout fragment container where i load fragments for different states on my app my question here is what can be the possible causes of such exception as i got it from crashlytic logs so do not know reproduce scenarios, here are logs

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.com.mycompanydomain/me.com.mycompanydomain.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instantiated fragment for index #0
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4921)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

As asked in comments the additional logs are below which shows it occurs in onCreate of MainActivity but there is no specific direction except occured on samsung device one time on Android 7, and one time on Android 8

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instantiated fragment for index #0
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:3097)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:149)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:306)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
   at me.com.mycompanydomain.ui.activities.NavDrawerActivity.onCreate(NavDrawerActivity.java:138)
   at me.com.mycompanydomain.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:180)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4978)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1648)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

**EDIT (fragment operation details)**

The `MainActivity` is calling `loadCurrentFragment();` inside `onCreate`

```
 private void loadCurrentFragment() {
    mCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (mCurrentFragment == null) {
        if(mAppState.getActiveNewsArticle() != null) {
            mCurrentFragment = new NewsArticleFragment();
            changeFrag();
        }
        else if (mAppState.getActiveChannel() != null) {
            mCurrentFragment = new ChannelFragment();
            changeFrag();
        }

    }
}

 private void changeFrag() {
    if (mCurrentFragment != null && !isFinishing()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frag_container, mCurrentFragment, CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Also inside `onResume` following code is being used

```
if (mAppState.getActiveNewsArticle() != null && !(mCurrentFragment instanceof NewsArticleFragment)) {
        mCurrentFragment = new NewsArticleFragment();
        changeFrag();
    }
    else if (mAppState.getActiveChannel() != null && !(mCurrentFragment instanceof ChannelFragment)) {
        mCurrentFragment = new ChannelFragment();
        changeFrag();
    }
```

Beside these places there are some some `EventBus` methods `onEventMainThread` which can check if current fragment is not what action requires then load current fragment with required one. Fragments are not being removed and only are being replaced while each of the above mentioned fragments which get loaded have also nested fragments.

Comment: Is there anything more to the stack trace?

Comment: Edited answer with additional info if you want to know about a specific info about way i implemented the code then let me know

Comment: Are you removing fragments at onDestroy or onStop? You shoud'nt

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos not removing then at all only replacing i have added further details in question.

Comment: Is there anything else in your `onCreate` call that is relying on the currently displayed fragment not being null? From what I can tell, it might be possible for the current fragment to be null, and both `mAppState.getActiveNewsArticle()` and `mAppState.getActiveChannel()` to potentially return null, meaning you never create a fragment to use. Is that possible?

Comment: @Acadian_Ghost `MianActivity` by default loads a `LobbyFragment` so this chance is low that `MainActivity` didn't had any fragment at time of error, what i suspect is there is some kind of fragment transaction causing this but as error is not reproducible on my device so not sure where to look for the cause any specification or Android documentation about this issue will be helpful so that i can understand what can be the originating causes for this type of issue. As my code is complex and it'll took a lot of time to suspect everything for this issue while i can't verify fix.